# How to apply a different texture to child objects using traverse?

Tags: javascript, three.js, traversal

I have an object loaded through `THREE.ObjectLoader()`, which I then traverse through.  The object is made up of a number of different elements, basically a box made up of panels and sticks, nothing complicated.

I need to assign a different texture to some of the child objects.

Unfortunately, the all of the object's textures (`material.map`) is taking the last set `map` from the loop.  Please see the example code:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("carport-scene-nocolor.json", function ( object ) {

    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var glass = textureLoader.load('glass2.jpg');
    var crate = textureLoader.load('crate.gif');

    object.traverse( function ( child )
    {
        child.receiveShadow = true;
        child.castShadow = true;

        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
            console.log(child.name);

            child.material.shininess = 100;
            child.material.wireframe = false;
            child.material.normalScale = new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 );

            if( child.name === 'wooden_slats3' ) {
                child.material.map = glass;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
            } else {
                child.material.map = crate;
                child.material.needsUpdate = true;
            }
        }
    });
    object.position.y = -1;
    object.position.x = 0;
    object.receiveShadow = true;
    object.castShadow = true;

    scene.add( object );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 50, 100 );
} );
```

If I check the console I can see the last element in the traverse is called 'wooden_slats4'.  I expect 'wooden_slats3' to be `glass` texture, but it isn't, everything is using the `crate` texture map.

If I play about with these values and change the if statement to check for `child.name === 'wooden_slats4'` then it applies it for everything, as that is the last child in the object.

I thought it might be an issue with how `object.traverse` works, but from what I've read online my approach is correct.

For reference, console output is:

```
pCube1
pCube2
pCube3
pCube4
wooden_slats2
wooden_slats3
wooden_slats4
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently editing `child.material` edits the global material, not just that child/JS object.

I needed to clone the child's material and apply that instead:

```
var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
objectLoader.load("carport-scene-nocolor.json", function ( object ) {

    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var glass = textureLoader.load('glass2.jpg');
    var crate = textureLoader.load('crate.gif');

    object.traverse( function ( child )
    {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
            console.log(child.name);

            var material = child.material.clone();

            material.shininess = 100;
            material.wireframe = false;
            material.normalScale = new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 );

            if( child.name === 'wooden_slats3' ) {
                material.map = glass;
            } else {
                material.map = crate;
            }
            child.material = material;
        }
    });
    object.position.y = -1;
    object.position.x = 0;
    object.receiveShadow = true;
    object.castShadow = true;

    scene.add( object );
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 50, 100 );
} );
```